# Cross validation desicion tree

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, tree, training-data

After making a desicion tree function, I have decided to check how accurate is the tree, and to confirm that atleast the first split is the same if I'll make another trees with the same data

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
import sys
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
```

.....

```
def desicion_tree(data_set:pd.DataFrame,val_1 : str, val_2 : str):
    #Encoder  -- > fit doesn't accept strings
    feature_cols = data_set.columns[0:-1]
    X = data_set[feature_cols] # Independent variables
    y = data_set.Mut #class
    y = y.to_list()
    le = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
    y = le.fit_transform(y)
    # Split data set into training set and test set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) # 75% 
    # Create Decision Tree classifer object
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth= 4, criterion= 'entropy')
    # Train Decision Tree Classifer
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # Predict the response for test dataset
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    #Perform cross validation
    for i in range(2, 8):
        plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
        # Perform Kfold cross validation
        #cv = ShuffleSplit(test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
        kf = KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle= True)
        scores = cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, n_jobs=4, cv=kf)
        print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
        tree.plot_tree(clf,filled = True,feature_names=feature_cols,class_names=[val_1,val_2])
        plt.show()
desicion_tree(car_rep_sep_20, 'Categorial', 'Non categorial')
```

Down , I wrote a loop in order to rectreate the tree with splitted values using Kfold. The accuracy is changing (around 90%) but the tree is the same, where did I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross_val_score` clones the estimator in order to fit-and-score on the various folds, so the `clf` object remains the same as when you fit it to the entire dataset before the loop, and so the plotted tree is that one rather than any of the cross-validated ones.

To get what you're after, I think you can use `cross_validate` with option `return_estimator=True`.  You also shouldn't need the loop, if your cv object has the number of splits desired:

```py
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
cv_results = cross_validate(
    estimator=clf,
    X=X,
    y=y,
    n_jobs=4,
    cv=kf,
    return_estimator=True,
)
print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (
    cv_results['test_score'].mean(),
    cv_results['test_score'].std(),
))
for est in cv_results['estimator']:
    tree.plot_tree(est, filled=True, feature_names=feature_cols, class_names=[val_1, val_2])
    plt.show();
```

Alternatively, loop manually over the folds (or other cv iteration), fitting the model and plotting its tree in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your respind. I change the cross_val_score with cross_validate, and it throws error of "'test_score': array([0.89256198, 0.90456432])} is not an estimator instance" with the parameters used before

Comment: Also, I won't be able to calculate standard deviation

Comment: I'm not sure what you did to make sklearn think the `test_score` value was supposed to be an estimator object... I've added a code sample that works locally (after dropping some of the optional parameters since I don't have your dataset).